# Time average of function having more than one frequencies

Tags: time-series

I have a function f(t), if this function has only one harmonic frequency then its time averaged can be calculated in straight forward manner. But suppose if it has two frequencies whose corresponding time period are $T_1$ and $T_2$, how will I calculate the time average?

If suppose $T_1>T_2$, will I calculate the time average with $T_1$, as this is a longer time scale.

Is this concept correct??

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I would recommend calculating the time average on a much longer time; in specific, over a time interval that is divisible by both $T_1$ and $T_2$. Then both of the oscillations have made an integer number of cycles.

Comment: @MattiP. So shall I use least common multiple of $(T_1,T_2)$ ?

Comment: @TSSingh Yes, I would start with that. If you're unsure of how to calculate the LCM of non-integers (if the times are not integers), try to google "LCM of fractions" or something similar.